# How do I adjust marquee based on global variable? - Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, meteor

I'm developing an app using Meteor Framework.

One of the features I am looking to implement is having a marquee text (like a scrolling bottom text).

I have added the package [meteor-jquery-marquee](https://atmospherejs.com/michalvalasek/jquery-marquee) and it works great with a single string. But whenever  I try to modify the string, nothing happens, and it stays the same.

It's worth mentioning that I did try sessions, and it changes the text, however, the marquee animation stops, which defeats the purpose.

I have been stuck for hours trying to get it to work, some help would really save my butt here.

I've initialized the global variable in the client/main.js as

```
globalMessage = "Welcome to my proJECT";
```

And it scrolls with the marquee just fine.

Thank you in advance!

My code:

My body template

```
<template name="App_Body">
  {{> Header}}
  {{>Template.dynamic template=main}}
  {{> Footer}}
  <div style="color: white;" class="ui center aligned container">
    <div class='marquee'>{{globalMessage}}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

body.js

```
Template.App_Body.helpers({
  globalMessage () {
    return globalMessage;
  },
});
```

where I'm trying to edit the marquee:

```
<template name="dailyMessageControl">
  <div class="container">
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="info pull-right"> <!-- column div -->
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
          <h1 class="panel-title text-center panel-relative"> Modify Daily Message</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="list-group">
          <div class="list-group-item">
            <p style="font-size: 30px;">Current Message: <br>{{globalMessage}}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-footer">
            <form>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Enter new messages</label>
                <input type="text" name="newMsg" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="New Message">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- end column div -->
  </div>
</template>
```

the .js

```
Template.dailyMessageControl.helpers({
  globalMessage () {
    return globalMessage;
  },
});

Template.dailyMessageControl.events({
  'submit form': function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var newMsg = event.target.newMsg.value;
    globalMessage = newMsg;
  }
});
```

Comment: Please, show also how (and where) do you initialize `$(...).marquee(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code clearly lacks reactivity, let's fix that.

Fist, initialize `globalMessage` as `ReactiveVar` instance (**`client/main.js`**):

```
globalMessage = new ReactiveVar('Welcome to my proJECT');
```

Next, code to react to its value change (**`body.js`**):

1. Remove `globalMessage()` helper
2. Add code that will track `globalMessage` variable and re-create `$.marquee`:

   ```
   Template.App_Body.onRendered(function appBodyOnRendered() {
     this.autorun(() => {
       const value = globalMessage.get();
       const $marquee = this.$('.marquee');
       $marquee.marquee('destroy');
       $marquee.html(value);
       $marquee.marquee(); // add your marquee init options here
     });
   });
   ```

And, lastly, update code in `dailyMessageControl` template to work with `ReactiveVar` instance:

```js
Template.dailyMessageControl.helpers({
  globalMessage () {
    return globalMessage.get(); // changed line
  },
});

Template.dailyMessageControl.events({
  'submit form': function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var newMsg = event.target.newMsg.value;
    globalMessage.set(newMsg); // changed line
  }
});
```

Comment: Hello again

This code works beautifully on a signle machine, but what if I want other machines to see the change as well? 

I have 3 devices connected to the localhost server, and when I change the marquee message, it only changes it on my machine, not the others. How can I fix that? 

Thank you for your time!

Comment: @Ibrahim You should save it to the DB then.